# Google Charts Line Graph seemingly goes back in time

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime, google-visualization

Im using the Google Charts API to make a line graph. For some reason, it looks like a few of the data points go back in time.

[image]

I'm not sure why this happens, whether it has to do with how I save the date to the MySQL database, or it's something to do with the API and javascript. I heard that months count from 0-11, not 1-12, but I don't think this is the problem because it's only dates from a few hours today.

Here's my code to save the date to a MySQL table:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$date = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql = "INSERT INTO prices (priceLBTC, dt)
VALUES ($bitcoinPrice, '$date')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Here's how I create the line graph:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawAxisTickColors);

function drawAxisTickColors() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Price');
      var dateArr2 = (<?php echo json_encode($dateArr); ?>).reverse();
    //     for (i = 0; i < dateArr2.length; i++) {
          //   dateArr2[i] = dateArr2[i].split(/[- :]/);
          // }
      var bitcoinArr = (<?php echo json_encode($bitcoinPriceArr); ?>).reverse();
      var length = Math.min(dateArr2.length, bitcoinArr.length);
      var rows = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    rows.push([new Date((dateArr2[i]).replace(/-/g, '/')), bitcoinArr[i]]);
  }

        data.addRows(rows);

      var options = {
        // backgroundColor: '#E4E4E4',
         curveType: 'function',
    chartArea: {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%"
    },
    hAxis: {
        textPosition: 'none',
        baselineColor: 'none',
        gridlines: {
            color: 'none'
        },
    },
    vAxis: {
        textPosition: 'none',
        baselineColor: 'none',
        gridlines: {
            color: 'none'
        }
    },
    colors: ['#2098d4', '#ffffff'],
    legend: 'none'
};
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Comment: it would be easier to answer if we could see the data, recreate the chart...

Comment: Try making sure your data is ordered the way you wish to draw them (ie sorted by time) before you draw the chart. This might solve your problem..